# Embeddable Reporting Service on Bluemix - EU GB region

Tags: ibm-cloud, cognos, embeddable-reporting

I tried binding a new Embeddable Reporting service into my sample application on bluemix on the domain eu-gb.mybluemix.net. Sample application uses liberty runtime with Cloudant NoSQL DB service and SQL DB services bound to it.

I get a pop-up indicating the URL endpoint https://erservice-impl.eu-gb.bluemix.net:443, prompting to enter the user id and password. Upon providing this, I'm requested to enter the information again.

Anyone who has surfaced this problem on the bluemix UK region..?

Thanks,
Raghavendra.

Comment: Tried using the Embeddable Reporting service (ERS) liberty sample in the US region, from the bluemix link - https://hub.jazz.net/project/ers/ERSJavaStepSample/overview. Found a bug - DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(m_authenticationInfo.getBytes(), authentication string encoded in the methods doConnect() and doVerb(). Fixed it by moving this code inside the constructor and initialize the encoded string.

Comment: I have asked the Embeddable Reporting Service Team to take a look at the sample.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is indeed in UK and AUS regions but not in US. We have a support issue open with the Embeddable Reporting Team about this and hope that will be resolved soon.